# Skip git commits with a specific string using git log

Tags: git, grep, commit, git-log

I would like to take the latest 5 commits using git log that do not contain a specific string, for example "Merge branch".

I tried several options, but none of them worked. e.g.:

```
 git log -n 5 --grep="Merge branch" --invert-grep
 git log -n 5 -v --grep="Merge branch"
 git log -n 5 --not --grep="Merge branch"
```

It seems that --invert-grep does the job but it doesn't work (http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're specifically trying to look for non-merge-commits, you can use:

```
git log -n 5 --no-merges
```

This will, of course, also skip merge commits that don't contain "Merge branch" in their log message.